# Reading MSMQ Messages in Raw XML

Tags: c#, xml, msmq

I am attempting to read the raw XML of an MSMQ message and save it to an XML file. For instance, the MSMQ message with body:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<string>Hello World! I am message #4</string>
```

I would like to take those exact xml lines and save them to a file message.xml.

I have the message reading like the below:

```
msg = queue.PeekById(enumerator.Current.Id);
                            msg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new String[] { "System.String,mscorlib" });
                            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(dirPath + @"\" + msg.Label.Replace(@"\","").Replace(@".","") + enumerator.Current.Id.Replace(@"\","").Replace(@".","") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmss") + ".xml", msg.Body.ToString());
                            queue.ReceiveById(enumerator.Current.Id);
                            logEntry("*-Received Message with Id " + msg.Id + " and Label " + msg.Label);
```

But that only pulls the text "Hello World! I am message #4" and I want the full xml.

Comment: Because you using xmlmessageformatter, have you tried another formatter?

Comment: @alsafoo What formatter would give me the raw xml from the messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
msg.Formatter = new ActiveXMessageFormatter();
reader = new StreamReader(msg.BodyStream);

var msgBody = reader.ReadToEnd(); // This gets the actual message as text
```

Formatters do not need to be symmetric - you can have different formatters on either end of the queue.

From here - http://andypiper.co.uk/2006/03/31/receiving-plain-text-messages-in-msmq/